# Nodejs (Generic Pool): release the resource when catching an error

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling

According to [node-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool), the process for acquiring a resource is like :

```
 const resourcePromise = myPool.acquire();
  resourcePromise
  .then(function(client) {
    client.query("select * from foo", [], function() {
      // return object back to pool
      myPool.release(client);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // handle error 
  });
```

Imagine that I have a scenario where an exception occurs while processing data ( after acquiring the resource and before releasing it )

Just like the following sample:

```
const resourcePromise = myPool.acquire();
resourcePromise
  .then(function(client) {
    client.query("select * from foo", [], function() {
      throw new Error('unknown error');
      myPool.release(client);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // how can I release the resource here?
  });
```

How can I release the resource then?

Comment: Curious, why do you need pool? What db driver are you using that it doesn't have it's own pooling implementation?

Comment: I'm using ripple-API, so I need connection pool to deal with it.otherwise, I need to establish a websocket connection with ripple's server for each request.

Comment: Cool, interesting stuff! And yes, exactly what node-pool should be used for, I guess.

Comment: By the way, I'm so grateful for your help, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways. Get the client hook globally:

```
let client;
resourcePromise
  .then(c=> {
      client = c;
      return query.whatever();
   })
  .catch(() => {
    resource.release(client);
  });
```

Or something like Bluebird's [`finally`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) could help:

```
let client;
resourcePromise
  .then(c=> {
      client = c;
   })
  .catch(/* whatever else */)
  .finally(() => {
    resource.release(client);
  })
```

You have to make sure to handle timeouts as well, though - in case the promise never resolves (successfully or not), you never get into any of the handlers.

Another way is to deal with the errors inside the promise chain:

```
resourcePromise.then(function (client) {
  return query.whatever(client)
    .catch(() => resource.release(client));
});
```